# Add row programatically to already filled (from database) datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Completely edited question: I am trying without success to add new row to datagridview, which is already populated with data from Access database and displayed on Form1. The way its already populated is that in Broker class I have method that returns data from database. I am calling that method from Form1 and assigning it to

```
datagridView.DataSource
```

[image: here is the pic]

I am calling Form1 from another form on button click after I enter values into txtfields and choose from combobox. 
The next part I am giving code especially *steps after* creating object of Form1 I am not sure that it is well at all. Please help me about that.

```
private void btnDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Prijava pr = new Prijava();
            pr.Datum = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text);

            pr.BrojIndeksa = Convert.ToInt32(txtBrInd.Text);
            pr.student = cbStudent.SelectedItem as Student;
            pr.predmet = cbPredmet.SelectedItem as Predmet;
            pr.Ocena = Convert.ToInt32(cbOcena.SelectedValue);
            listaprijava.Add(pr);
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)f1.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
            row.Cells["BrojIndeksa"].Value = pr.BrojIndeksa;
            row.Cells["Student"].Value = pr.student;
            row.Cells["Predmet"].Value = pr.predmet;
            row.Cells["Ocena"].Value = pr.Ocena;
            f1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: Is the list bound to the DataGridView DataSource?

Comment: How are you binding/adding the original data to the datagridview?

Comment: no I created new list as I was thinking I will bound new data that way. For existing data from database, I had another list as DataSource

Comment: Then after adding the record to your list, you need to call dataGridView.DataSource = list;  dataGridView.DataBind();

Comment: I have Broker class which has method that I am connecting to database, executing sql query, and returning list. than I am calling that method from form, and dgv.DataSource = Broker.dajSesiju().thatMethod();

Comment: @Mangist I tried already dgv.DataSource = list; (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.). DataBind() doesnt exist

Comment: Is dgv null? The NullReferenceException indicates it is.

Comment: I forgot to set pr.Ocena which is combo box. But the thing is that I cant do cbOcena.SelectedItem as NameOfTheClass; because Ocena is property of class Prijava. How am I supposed to do that ?

Comment: Your question is all over the place.

Comment: @LarsTech well It is because I was finding out various things while reading comments. I edited question now.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the null error?

Comment: @LarsTech dgv.DataSource = list;

Comment: @JohnG thanks I am figuring out your solution :)

Comment: From the code you posted, the list is not null.  Is the grid in the same form as that list?  Are you setting the list to null somewhere else in your code?

Comment: yes you are totally right! dgv is on another form ! `public DataGridView dgv { get; set; }` and on another form `Form2 f2 = new Form2()  f2.dgv = dataGridView1;` Can You please help me fix this exception ?

Comment: I don't know enough about your code, but I would pass the list around, not a grid.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks !

Comment: @LarsTech I cant find solution at all, but shouldnt be that difficult... I edited question completely. Is there a way to somehow reset question on top for others to see it, because I am not getting new views because some time passed after I posted it and I edited it completely?

Comment: You are making a *new* form1, which you don't show.  I'm guessing you don't want to show that one, but the one that already exists on the screen.  That means you need to pass a reference to the *existing* Form1 that is visible on the screen.

Comment: maybe I dont get it. `Form1 f1;` is  Form which contains datagridview. and I am creating object f1 so I can add row to dgv from another form (smaller one). I am not sure at all for the code I provided after I called creation of Form1 instance. As for exception now I am getting index out of range at the line `DataGridViewRow row =(DataGridViewRow)f1.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();`. If You can think of fix to this with provided code would be great. I really cant fix it, unfortunately :)

Comment: The code you posted shows you are making a new Form1 named f1.  No where in your code do you "show" this form.  So it never becomes visible and gets destroyed later after your click event completes its code.

Comment: @LarsTech You are right again. If you find some time, please post an answer on how to get what I am trying to. I want to add row on datagridview after clicking button on smaller form. bigger form is called Form1. Later I will add another method to save that row in database. I will try to do it myself again later, thanks again. lets not post comments anymore, I am bothering you, but I am not able to solve it yet this way. Thanks again